# Tensorflow 2.0 - No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, pytorch

I'm a beginner to Tensorflow 2.0. I have worked extensively with PyTorch and finding it difficult to find parallels to Tensorflow 2.0 for my current work, with the available documentation. I would appreciate any help with this task:

I have a pre-trained decoder of the VAE of the [GHUM human body model](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Xu_GHUM__GHUML_Generative_3D_Human_Shape_and_Articulated_Pose_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf). Since the decoder code is proprietary (Google's), I don't have the permission to post that here. But I hope I can describe the problem without that, with my code snippets which I'm allowed to share. The decoder takes a Shape latent code and a Pose latent code, and outputs a body mesh in that shape and pose. What I want to do, is to keep the decoder fixed and optimize for the latent shape and pose code against a given target. That is, optimize the shape/pose in the latent space, to get a shape that best matches a target shape I have.

How I'd do this in Pytorch, is to initialize Pose and Shape latent vectors with `torch.nn.Parameter` and initialize an optimizer with the list of parameters, and keeping the decoder frozen would simply be setting its `requires_grad_ = False`.

In TF2.0 however, it doesn't seem to be as straightforward.

My code is as below:

```
 class Projection(Model):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Projection, self).__init__()
      self.joint_angles_type = "EULER"

  def call(self,shape,pose):
      pose_parameters = ghum_pose_params(
          body_shape_code=shape,
          skeleton_posing_values=pose)
      posed_data = ghum_shape_pose(pose_parameters)

      return posed_data.vertices
```

Now, I call initialize and try to optimize as below:

```
pose = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1, num_pose_params),tf.float32))
shape = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1, shape_code_size)))
model = Projection()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
          loss=loss_fn)
vertices = model(shape,pose)
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        chamfer_distance = loss_fn(vertices[0,:,:],target_vertices)
        gradients = tape.gradient(chamfer_distance, [pose,shape])
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [pose,shape]))
```

When I do this, I get the error as below:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is...

I'd like to know how to fix this error, and what's the general pipeline for doing something like this in TF. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was a bug in my code:

The part where I call the `model()` should be inside the `with` statement as below:

```
pose = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1, num_pose_params),tf.float32))
shape = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1, shape_code_size)))
model = Projection()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
          loss=loss_fn)
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        vertices = model(shape,pose) # this line should be here.
        chamfer_distance = loss_fn(vertices[0,:,:],target_vertices)
        gradients = tape.gradient(chamfer_distance, [pose,shape])
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [pose,shape]))
```